# SharePoint 2013 WebPart Timer not ticking

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I'm looking for solution to Async reload webpart. In most solutions code looks like below, but code doesn't work. Timer.Tick does't fire:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YandexWeather-VisualWebPart.ascx.cs" Inherits="InfoTable_SP2013WebPart.YandexWeather_VisualWebPart.YandexWeather_VisualWebPart" %>

<div id="Weather" class="b-weather">
    <asp:Image ID="WeatherImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="http://info.weather.net/moscow/4.ru.png" />

     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Ajax"></asp:Label>

  <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick" OnLoad="Timer2_Load" >
  </asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="NewItemTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
        <asp:Button ID="uxSubmit" runat="server" onclick="Timer2_Tick" Text="Добавить" />
        <asp:Label ID="IbIResult" runat="server" Text="Ajax"></asp:Label>
    <!-- Ajax ends here with -->


    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for async timer control your missing the trigger control within the update panel:

you need to add:

```
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="" EventName="" />
        </Triggers>
```

so code would be:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YandexWeather-VisualWebPart.ascx.cs" Inherits="InfoTable_SP2013WebPart.YandexWeather_VisualWebPart.YandexWeather_VisualWebPart" %>

<div id="Weather" class="b-weather">
    <asp:Image ID="WeatherImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="http://info.weather.net/moscow/4.ru.png" />

     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Ajax"></asp:Label>

  <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick" OnLoad="Timer2_Load" >
  </asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxSubmit" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="NewItemTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
        <asp:Button ID="uxSubmit" runat="server" onclick="button2_Click" Text="Добавить" />
        <asp:Label ID="IbIResult" runat="server" Text="Ajax"></asp:Label>
    <!-- Ajax ends here with -->


    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>  

</div>
```

also like to note that this is the aspx code that is the client side part. You didn't show what you have done for the server side? Your calling the event Timer2_Tick within the aspx button. Within your .cs you should have a method like:

```
int tickCounter = 0;

protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    IbIResult.Text = "refreshed at: "+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
    tickCounter++;

    if(tickCounter == 100)
    {
        Timer2.Stop();
        Timer2.Enabled = false;
    }
}


protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tickCounter =0;
    Timer2.Enabeld = true;
    Timer2.Start();
}
```

the code above (.cs) calls or runs the timer code. It enables and starts the timer event.... it sets the counter to 0 every time the button is clicked. when the timer runs it runs for 10 second intervals and in each interval it prints to the label that current datetime at that second. it will then add 1 to the counter variable and will repeat every ten seconds till the counter reaches 100 and then it stops the timer!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx

---

**EDIT**

ahh so you want this on a webpart? goto visual studios and when creating a new project make sure you select sharepoint 2013 and then select webparts, it will set it all up for you with a template. If you select visual template than it would give you ascx for front end and .cs for code behind. If its just a standard webpart than it will only be .cs

this is what your code should look like if its visual webpart! below is the ascx. Just copy and past after the following:

```
<div id="Weather" class="b-weather">

  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1" />

  <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
  </asp:Timer>

  <asp:Image ID="WeatherImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="http://info.weather.net/moscow/4.ru.png" />
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Ajax"></asp:Label>


  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="NewItemTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
        <asp:Label ID="IbIResult" runat="server" Text="Ajax"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>

   <asp:Button ID="uxSubmit" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="TimerFrequency" runat="server" onclick="button2_Click" Text="Добавить" />
</div>
```

the .cs still applies from earlier post!

issue was button was within updatepanel without autopostback? i presume you want a button when clicked to update the page without postback?

if you want to know step by step on visual webpart than follow this pictured tut:

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/visual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.html

and for the timer job:

https://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UsingTimerControlTutorial.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc295400.aspx

what exactly are you trying todo? do you want the code within a webpart, within that webpart you have a button that is clicked that triggers the timer control that updates the label within the update panel? or do i have this wrong?

Comment: Thx for quick reply. Im make changes like you say, but it still not working. This is cs code: http://pastebin.com/PSifSNbG this is asp code: http://pastebin.com/t9pM8k7U

Comment: i test this code on empty website - it not working, but if i add   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /> - work fine. BUT on WebPart this code freeze page loading to 1 minute and more, and throw error timeout load execute... Any ideas how use async reload on timer?

Comment: I'm trying create simple ajax update webpart with timer and image that will be refreshed every N seconds(webpart show image). Timer not fire, manualy ajax update working

Answer (score -1):

You must add :

```
 <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RefreshTimer" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
```

and you put in control id of the timer